# How can I set my program to run until get an error and so that if it gets an error it will try again?

Tags: python, background

I have a piece of code that will constantly act on the database and keep it updated, but there is no network outage etc. For some reason, the program is prone to error. I want the program to run every 240 seconds and repeat the process up to 3 times if it gets an error, and if it gets an error 3 times, I want it to return to its old period, that is, every 240 seconds, can you help with this? I would also be very grateful if you could provide information so that I can make my program run in the background.

```
import time


class mysql_connections():
  def ___init__(self):
      .
      .
      .
  def table_query(self):
      .
      .
      .
...
if __name__ == "__main__":
delay = 10
sql = mysql_connections()
while 1:
    try:
        time.sleep(delay)
        sql.table_query()
        delay = 240
    except:
        delay = 10
```

I tried that but it's not clear so much

Comment: How about `try` and `except` combined with a `while` loop?

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using an exception handler? This can catch errors without your script crashing, for example:

```
try:
    int('hello')
except:
    print('That didn't work!')
```

For your case, you could add in somewhere near the start of your script:

```
error_count = 0
```

Then for your exception handler do:

```
try:
    # your code here
except:
    error_count += 1
```

Then somewhere near the end:

```
if error_count == 3:
    # change period to 240 seconds
```

General exception handlers aren't considered very Pythonic and it's better if you can narrow down the exception if you know the specific error that will be thrown, for example `int('hello')` will throw a `ValueError`. So it'd be better to write:

```
try:
    int('hello')
except ValueError:
    print('That can't be converted to an integer!')
```